# RxSwift cache operator for Completable

Tags: rx-swift

I am willing to replay the last result of a `Completable`, I believe exactly like what the [`.cache()` operator described here](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#cache--).

The following RxSwift code outputs: "completed"

```swift
let connectable = Completable.empty().asObservable().replay(1)
connectable.subscribe(onCompleted: { print("completed") })
connectable.connect()
```

Now if I `.connect()` before I `.subscribe()`, I don't get anything:

```swift
let connectable = Completable.empty().asObservable().replay(1)
connectable.connect()
connectable.subscribe(onCompleted: { print("completed") })
```

In my case, if I `.subscribe()` after `connectable` has completed, I want to know that it has completed...

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not care for the possibility to connect but simply desire a caching behavior, there is a very simple implementation for the `cache` operator:

```
extension PrimitiveSequence where TraitType == CompletableTrait, ElementType == Swift.Never {
  public func cache() -> Observable<ElementType> {
    return self.asObservable().share(replay: 1, scope: .forever)
  }
}
```

---

If, on the other hand, you care for the *connectability* of your observable, a [look at the source code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/65efb404c80fe1b23108c8fbb57d05b615e21c93/RxSwift/Observables/ShareReplayScope.swift#L147) for the above replay operator gives you the implementation for the desired behavior:

```
extension PrimitiveSequence where TraitType == CompletableTrait, ElementType == Swift.Never {
  public func cache() -> ConnectableObservable<ElementType> {
    return self.asObservable().multicast(ReplaySubject.create(bufferSize: 1))
  }
}
```

Multicast is a tricky operator.

It takes the events from the source observable (self) and sends them to the subject it is passed. It will then forward this subject's values to any subscribers.

The subscription to the source observable only happens when the result from multicast is *connected to*, through the `connect` call.

In the present use case, because ReplaySubject behaves like a cache, this usage of multicast enables any further subscriber to receive the values emmited by the source.

Comment: Great insights! What is the difference between your first `cache` implementation and the `share` operator that you link? I understand that the second implementation makes it connectable, but I don't see what makes the first implementation different from, say, `Completable.empty().asObservable().share(replay: 1).asCompletable()`

Comment: Oh, is it different because of the reference counting, meaning that `share()` will actually not replay the stop events but rather re-subscribe?

Comment: Only difference between the two is indeed the call to refCount, that will transform the ConnectableObservable into a regular Observable. In the case where scope is `.whileConnected`, you can see in the implementation uses a factory function to rebuild the underlying ReplaySubject, effectively re-running the side effects if a subscription occurs after the subscribers count drops to zero.

Comment: I get an error when trying your first implementation, though: `error: value of type 'PrimitiveSequence<CompletableTrait, Never>' has no member 'replay'; did you mean 'delay'?`

Comment: Oops, I forgot to call asObservable. Update my answer, should work like a charm now.

Comment: And `replay` doesn't take a `scope` :-)

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/65efb404c80fe1b23108c8fbb57d05b615e21c93/RxSwift/Observables/ShareReplayScope.swift#L141
Yes it does. What version of the library are you using? If you cannot upgrade, you can use the second version I posted here and stick a call to `refCount()` at the end to duplicate this behavior.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187835/discussion-between-jonesv-and-tomahh).